# Comparing Java memory heap dumps: Memory profiling for Java desktop application

Tags: java, memory-management, profiling

This is a more specific question to follow up on [another question that I have asked recently] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752714/memory-profiling-for-java-desktop-application). A correct answer for this question will earn a correct answer for that previous question too (since that is still in limbo)!

Basically I have a Java desktop application with a memory leak issue. I am using the memory profiler in NetBeans IDE to profile the memory issue. These are the steps that I have taken done so far:

1. Attach a new memory profiler to the NetBeans project
2. Define profiling points at several careful chosen lines of code, and set them to trigger a memory heap dump
3. Run the application in profiling mode

The end result of this is that I have several memory dumps saved to disk in `*.hprof` files. NetBeans IDE lets me peruse the contents (basic sort and search) of these memory dumps, and even lets me *walk the heap*, by seeing what the references contained within each instance,  and what other objects reference each instance. That is all good, and I have been able to identify 1 or 2 fairly obvious memory leaks and rectify about 15% of the problem thus far.

However, right now the method I am using relies on creating **hypotheses about which objects should NOT be in memory** at a particular point of time, and then investigating those. What I am after now is a **way to compare two separate heap dumps**: Basically I have two heap dumps that should be almost the same, because the application has been restored to the same state.

However, one is before the memory leak, and the other after the memory leak, and so they are obviously different. If I am able to **compare these two heaps using a of tool**, instead of manually as I am doing now, then I need not rely on hypotheses to identify where the leaks are occurring, and can just have the tool identify them for me.

This is important for me because of the the sheer number of classes and instances involved for this particular application (700+ and millions, respectively)

Is the NetBeans IDE's profiler capable of doing this?

If not, is there a tool out there that is able to perform this task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [jhat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html).  Specifically look at the option(-baseline baseline-dump-file)  on the page I reference it says the following:

"Specify a baseline heap dump. Objects in both heap dumps with the same object ID will be marked as not being "new". Other objects will be marked as "new". This is useful while comparing two different heap dumps."

this may help when comparing the two heap dumps.

Comment: That requires both heap dumps to be from the same run of the application (which doesn't seem like it'd be a problem from bguiz).

Comment: @broschb, +1, Thank you - this works for me! My only issue with JHAT is that it's interface is via a fairly static webpage, not very user friendly. That being said being able to walk the heap dump using `References to this object`, and being able to filter those with `New Instances/Include subclasses`, was exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 31):

There is also a **free, GUI** tool for this task: [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/). It lets you take several heap dumps and then tell it to compare one with another, displaying the differing contents as a list, with a **graphical representation of each element's share of used memory**. Also, interactively browsing the heap dump difference is much **more comfortable than with jhat**.

[image: VisualVM 1.4.4 compare capability]

Comment: It would be nice if the person who downvoted my answer explained to me why she/he did it. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think your answer is good +1

Comment: I have taken a couple heap dumps with VisualVM; now how do I compare them?

Comment: still not answered and it is certainly not obvious in the UI.

Comment: found it. in the Summary tab, upper right, there is a "compre two heap dumps" link. Less filling, tastes great.

Comment: Please explain how to do it, in particular, the VisualVM version and some screenshots would help.

Comment: Apparently, this feature is not available anymore.

Comment: It's been moved to the top-right corner of "classes" inside the heap dump screen.

Comment: It seems to be gone in the latest VisualVM 2.0. The option is still present in JDK 8 version.

Comment: In latest versions of VisualVM the feature is still present, just moved in the GUI. To access, take a heap dump, click on the drop-down on its top left (should be "Summary" initially) and select "Objects" to view the content. Then immediately to the right of that dropdown, a new button appears which when pressed triggers the "compare heap dump" feature.

Answer (score 4):

YourKit can [compare heap dumps](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/compare_snapshots.jsp).

Comment: The answer contains a dead link. Please consider replacing the link by the content of yourkit in order to prevent dead link due to website refactoring (https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/compare_snapshots.jsp)